# Build glib from source

Tags: glib, libffi

Good morning, I'm trying to build glib from source, but nevertheless several attempts always get this error:

```
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `gobject.stp.in', needed by `gobject.stp'.  Stop.
```

I'm using these commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/gt --with-pcre=internal LIBFFI_CFLAGS=-I/opt/gt/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include LIBFFI_LIBS="-L/opt/gt/lib64 -lffi"

make
```

someone can help me?

Comment: That file should be included with glib.  Where did you get the sources?

Comment: From the Gtk+ project download page. http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php

Comment: What version, exactly?  Preferably a link to the exact tarball you downloaded.

Comment: V2.48 http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.48/

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the 2.48.0 tarball; see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763821

You can work around the issue by passing `--disable-systemtap` to the configure script.